# Format ggplot2 time series data

Tags: r, matrix, ggplot2, graph, timeserieschart

I'm trying to generate a neat line plot in gpplot

Setup:

```
list1 <- c()
for (i in 1:100) {
  list1[[i]]= paste("date",i, sep="_")
}

mat <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=100, ncol=2))
mat[,1] = list1
mat[,2] = rnorm(100,0,1)
colnames(mat) = c("date", "number")
ggplot(mat) + geom_line(aes(x=date, y=number, group=1)) +xlab("date") + ylab("number")
```

When i run this code, the x-axis cannot be interpreted. How do i fix this?

Comment: `class(mat$date)`: [1] "character". Your `date` variable is  "character", not "date". You need to generate a date variable first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the `date` column have to be a character? If you set it to an actual date `ggplot` will take care of it for you.

```
start = as.Date("2005-01-01")
end = start + 99
dates <- seq(from = start, to = end, by = "day")



mat <- NULL
mat$dates <- dates
mat$number = rnorm(100,0,1)
mat <- as.data.frame(mat)


ggplot(mat) +
  geom_line(aes(x = dates, y=number, group=1)) +
  xlab("date") + 
  ylab("number")
```

Comment: This is helpful! thanks! is it possible to convert the first column to an 'date' form from character?

Comment: The for loop in your data creates the following values `"date_1"   "date_2"   "date_3"   "date_4"   "date_5" ... ` You want to chnage these to dates?

Comment: I'm using the for loop to create data in the same form as my actual dataset. My actual dataset has data in the form: "Mar.94", "Jun.94" etc. However, the command as.date doesn't seem to work.